# Max resolution for external monitor on Dell E6420 (Intel Graphics HD 3000)

Tags: external-display, dell-latitude

I've got an E6420 with a Core i7 sporting the HD3000 chipset. I'm considering getting an external monitor and have found a good deal for 27" Dell UltraSharp monitor. I'm tempted to order it, but to my surprise it's hard to find out whether or not I'd be able to actually use all the native pixels in this combination, since this rather nice IPS panel has a resolution of 2560x1440. It'd be nice to be able to look at 3 of the 18 megapixels from my digital camera at once..!

I *think* the chipset would have no problem with this resolution (except for gaming, which is of little interest to me). It handles 2 monitors in 1920x1200 according to answers here on superuser, so the pixel count at least can't be any issue. But I *think* outputting anything beyond 1920x1200 over HDMI may well be, and the E6420 doesn't have a DisplayPort. Finally, I *think* Dell has a dock that works with this model that does have a DisplayPort.

But I don't actually know if it would work! The screen is a bit expensive and I would hate to buy a high-end product only to have to run it at something other than native resolution, leading to much poorer image quality than a cheap monitor at native resolution. Of course a screen like this should last me many years, but even so... I'd really prefer to know that it will work before shelling out for it.

Answer (score 2):

Does your motherboard have a display port adapter? It looks like they should support up to 2560x1600 on the HD 3000. However, I have never tried, nor verified this personally.

Source: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics/

[image]

Comment: I can verify that it does, if the board is properly designed to support it.

Comment: I for one trust intel, I haven't had any bad experiences to date.

Comment: Worst case, 30 day return policy.